# $Cos^2(\varphi) = 1/2$? What is $\varphi$?

Tags: trigonometry

Ok. I know this may sound silly but some reason, I am struggling to understand why the answer $\pi/4$.

Like what I did was take the square root of both sides to get cos($\varphi$) = 1/$\sqrt2$. Then I ask myself what value of phi would get me 1/$\sqrt2$. So, I start a 0 degrees at the top of the z-axis and find my way say the following:

$\pi$/6 => $\sqrt3$/2

$\pi$/4 => $\sqrt2$/2

$\pi$/3 => $\sqrt1$/2

So I said $\pi/3$

***I must confess that I think I basically rephrase this question by treating this like cos(x) = 1/2 and recreating this in the x-y plane like basic elementary work.

Comment: $1/\sqrt{2} \ne \sqrt{1}/2$, $1/\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have noted that $\cos{\pi/3}=1/2$ This is correct, but it is not the answer you want. You want $\cos{\phi} = 1/\sqrt{2}$.

Hint: Rationalize $1/\sqrt{2}$ by multiplying the top and bottom by $\sqrt{2}$. What do you get?

Comment: Wow! How did I not see this? hahaha Thanks so much!!!